# Which is Faster and More Efficient: Convert.ToInt32() or Ternary Operator?

Tags: c#, .net, int, boolean, ternary-operator

If I have to convert a `bool` into an `int` in C#, which of the following two options would be faster and more efficient?

```
int x = Convert.ToInt32(someBool);
```

Or

```
int x = someBool ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you disassemble `Convert.ToInt32(bool value)` you'll see how it is implemented:

```
public static int ToInt32(bool value)
{
    return value ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Reference: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,d75d8ee9b3529289

Comment: Ah! Perfect! Thanks for adding the reference as I was about to ask for it so that I can look things up myself next time 